# detecting signal coming from another motion sensor that triggers camera's shutter

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a motion sensor (used for camera trapping) that sends a signal to the camera to trigger the shutter. I am trying to use Arduino to turn on lights for 10 seconds by getting the signal from the motion sensor. I know there are ways to use motion sensor that can be used with Arduino. However, I need to know how I can detect a signal coming from the sensor to feed it to Arduino. I have tried connecting the cable from the sensor to A0, wrote a simple code to print the value of A0 but the serial monitor of Arduino shows nothing.

Comment: what motion sensor?

Comment: I guess the motion sensor is some third party product, which is not designed for the use with Arduinos. In that case you need to find out, what voltage levels and signal type the sensor uses. For the Uno the voltage has to be in the range of 5V. The type is most probable a digital signal. You need to find out, if it is active low or active high (active meaning the state, where the sensor is triggered). Amd whem the serial monitor doesm't show anything, then either your code or the setting of the serial monitor is wrong. Please look into this and then give more information in your question

Comment: What motion sensor? What code?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Here is the sensor:
[Scout Trail Monitor](https://cognisys-inc.com/scout-camera-trapping/scout-standard.html)

This a very advanced motion sensor which uses modulated IR beam and the only way for me to detect any signal (without taking the expensive equipment in parts) is to see what is coming from 3.5 mm shutter cable.

The very basic code to print:
```void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);}

 void loop() {
  Serial.print("Value: ");
  Serial.println(analogRead(0));
  delay(1000);
}```

Comment: Please no code in the comments. You need to add all this information to your question by editing it. Also: you are trying to read from pin 0, which is the Serial interface. You need to read from A0

Comment: That's correct. I used A0.

Comment: Also, with multimeter set to 20k resistance, I can see some increase to about 16k

Comment: If you use the HC-SR501 motion sensor, see [this tutorial](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-motion-sensor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all camera shutter cables are simple switches. They are an open circuit until you want to press the shutter, and then the switch closes. There is no voltage out of the shutter release, and so nothing for an analog pin to detect.

Many cameras have a shutter half-press switch that activates the light meter/auto-focus, and then a second switch that closes the shutter.

For a simple RCA plug shutter release or mono 3.5 mm plug shutter release, it's probably just a simple single pole switch. Wire one wire from the shutter release to a digital pin, and the other wire to ground. Set the pin to INPUT_PULLUP, and wait for it to go LOW. When it goes LOW the shutter is being pressed.

Be aware that a modulated IR shutter trap will be a little slow. It probably won't catch subjects like birds flying at high speed until the bird has moved past the point where the trap is pointed. For that you would want a laser beam and a fast phototransistor. Those can be fast enough and accurate enough to measure the speed of a bullet. (Although you need to read port registers directly in order to get fast enough response for that. `DigitalRead()` is too slow.)

Comment: Thanks for the great advise which helped me to detect the signal. Now I can see the output changes from 1 to 0 when. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: If I've answered your question then you should accept my answer. (click the check mark.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am typing this here coz I don't have enough rep to comment. Anywho, most of the motion sensors involve PIR tech, so the best way is to connect your PIR Signal pin from your sensor to any analog pin of your arduino and test the kind of signal you're getting when the environment is idle and when movement is detected, Keep in mind of the region that the sensor covers too (ROI). That will tell you some things,

- If the sensor works or not.
- If the sensor value is analog or digital
- If the sensor is active high or low
- Trial and error on the actual ROI

After all that you can write your code around it.